# How to remove pattern from items in an array

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a new array from an already existing array, where all the items in the array has a pattern in it.

For example

```
my_array=['A_1.gi.kl','BC_1.gi.kl','FGKX_1.gi.kl']
```

What I want is a function that can automatically make

```
my_new_array=['A','BC','FGKX']
```

How can I do this easily? The resulting items in the array don't have an identical length.

Answer (score 2):

Use `split` with a comprehension:

```
my_array = ['A_1.gi.kl', 'BC_1.gi.kl', 'FGKX_1.gi.kl']
my_new_array = [item.split('_')[0] for item in my_array]
```

Comment: You could use .replace to just do string substitution instead of creating a new array (within your list comprehension).

Answer (score 1):

You can get element up to certain character by using `list.index` if all of your elements have that character( as you have mentioned)

```
[v[:v.index('_')] for v in my_array]
['A', 'BC', 'FGKX']
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the suffix:

```
>>> suffix = '_1.gi.kl'
```

Then just split by the suffix:

```
>>> [item.split(suffix)[0] for item in my_array]
['A', 'BC', 'FGKX']
>>>
```

Comment: If you're going to use a fixed suffix you might as well just truncate each string by the length of that suffix: `suffix = len('_1.gi.kl'); [item[:-suffix] for item in my_array]`.